# How to effectively remove objectionable content from a twitter like app?

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

So my twitter like app got rejected because Apple wants me to delete objectional content within 24 hours. As I use Firebase this is somewhat a challenge, since I couldn't find any functions for this in the admin panel.

Let's assume a user reported a message with a unique `messageId` that should be deleted. I need to delete it from several locations:

Most of them are located at `/feeds/$userId/messageId` 
where `$userId` is the id of one of the followers of the user that posted the malicious content.

But what happens if one of the users stopped following the user before the admin could perform all the remove operations? He will still see the message in his timeline.

What I am trying to say is: Is there any admin tool that loops through all nodes and deletes every sub-node that matches a specified `messageId`?